# VBA Run Time error 91 while finishing loop

Tags: vba, loops, time

I have a question about my code somehow I get the following error(I tried some different solutions on the net, but somehow it doesnt solve my problem). I get the following error after ending the loop(while everything works in the loop): Run Time-error '91' object variable or with block variable not set. I hope one of you can help me! There is also an note where I get the error.

Code:

```
Public Function FilterButton() As Integer
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet, ParSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Dim SrcCell As Range, DestCell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iLastRow As Long, zLastRow As Long
    Dim Collection As String, System As String, Tag As String
    Dim iRowInWsPar As Long
    Dim iError As Integer
    Dim TagAndSystem As String, Value As String

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    '~~> Set your sheet
    Set SrcSheet = Sheets("Imported Data")
    Set ParSheet = Sheets("Parameters")

    '~~> Set your ranges
    '~~> Find Last Row in Col A in the source sheet
    iLastRow = SrcSheet.Range("A" & SrcSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set SourceRange = SrcSheet.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    '~~> Search values
    Collection = Trim(Range("lblImportCollection").Value)
    System = Trim(Range("lblImportSystem").Value)
    Tag = Trim(Range("lblImportTag").Value)
    TagAndSystem = System & Tag

    With SourceRange
        '~~> Match 1st Criteria ("Collection")
         Set SrcCell = .Find(What:=Collection, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not SrcCell Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = SrcCell.Address
            Do
            'If match 2nd Criteria
            If ((Len(Trim(System)) = 0) Or (UCase(SrcCell.Offset(, 1).Value) = UCase(System))) Then
                'Match 3rd criteria
                If ((Len(Trim(Tag)) = 0) Or (UCase(SrcCell.Offset(, 2).Value) = UCase(TagAndSystem))) Then

                    iRowInWsPar = FindCellfromWsPar(System, Tag)
                    Value = SrcCell.Offset(, 4).Value
                    'Found in the parameter worksheet
                    If iRowInWsPar <> -1 Then
                        iError = ChangeValueinWsPar(iRowInWsPar, Value)
                    End If

                End If
            End If

            Set SrcCell = .FindNext(After:=SrcCell)
            Loop While (Not SrcCell Is Nothing) And (SrcCell.Address <> firstAddress) 'here i get the error
        End If
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    FilterButton = 0

End Function


'This function will return the row (if found) of the "Parameters" worksheet
Public Function FindCellfromWsPar(sSystem As String, sTag As String) As Integer

    Dim ParSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ParRange As Range
    Dim SrcCell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim iLastRow As Long


    Set ParSheet = Sheets(mcsWorksheetParameters)
    With ParSheet
        iLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set ParRange = ParSheet.Range("A2:A" & iLastRow)

    FindCellfromWsPar = -1

    With ParRange
        '~~> Find sSystem in the "System" column
        Set SrcCell = .Find(What:=sSystem, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        '~~> If found
        If Not SrcCell Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = SrcCell.Address
            Do
            'If match Tag
            If (UCase(SrcCell.Offset(, 1).Value) = UCase(sTag)) Then
                FindCellfromWsPar = SrcCell.Row

            End If

            Set SrcCell = .FindNext(After:=SrcCell)
            Loop While (Not SrcCell Is Nothing) And (SrcCell.Address <> firstAddress)
        End If
    End With

End Function

Public Function ChangeValueinWsPar(iRow As Long, sValue As String)

    Dim ParSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sValCol As String

    sValCol = "G"
    Set ParSheet = Sheets(mcsWorksheetParameters)

    ParSheet.Range(sValCol & CStr(iRow)).Value = sValue

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you get the error because of what you ask the code to do here:

```
Loop While (Not SrcCell Is Nothing) And (SrcCell.Address <> firstAddress) 'here i get the error
```

You check if SrcCell is nothing. But just in case srcCell is nothing, it cannot return to you the Address, since the range is not set.

You can solve this problem by nesting the second condition in the first one. 
This way, you cannot ask for the address of an empty object.

Edit: What you can do for example is loop on the first condition, and enter the second condition at the start of the next loop.

Comment: Hmmm thats sounds logical, what do you suggest as an solution?

Comment: Still getting the error, trying to nest.. but I can't get it to work :(

Comment: Do you get the error on "SrcCell.Address" ? Debug this and check if the SrcCell is actually set.

Comment: `If srcCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do`, `Loop While srcCell.Address <> firstAddress`

Comment: thanks LS_dev and Kim Gysen :) Got it working the answer is

`If srcCell Is Nothing Then Exit Do, Loop While srcCell.Address <> firstAddress `